# Mysql Query for getting last 8 days data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data of last 8 days using the following query. However I am getting an extra record for the current day. Following is the query:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),
  IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(ar_stime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
  IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(ar_etime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
  IFNULL(ar_eltime,' '), 
  IF(ar_status='Aborted','Running',ar_status)
FROM etl.etl_status 
WHERE date =CURDATE()

UNION

SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),
  IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(ar_stime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
  IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(ar_etime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
  IFNULL(ar_eltime,' '),
  ar_status
FROM etl.etl_status es 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your question is of low quality, which doesnt help getting help. Please include the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use for a date 8 days ago:

```
select date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),
ifnull(date_format(ar_stime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(date_format(ar_etime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(ar_eltime,' '), 
if(ar_status='Aborted','Running',ar_status)
from etl.etl_status 
where date =CURDATE()
union
select date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),
ifnull(date_format(ar_stime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(date_format(ar_etime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(ar_eltime,' '),
ar_status
from etl.etl_status es 
WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -8 DAY);
```

Check the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) documentation.

Or you can use:

```
select date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),
ifnull(date_format(ar_stime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(date_format(ar_etime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(ar_eltime,' '), 
if(ar_status='Aborted','Running',ar_status)
from etl.etl_status 
where date =CURDATE()
union
select date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),
ifnull(date_format(ar_stime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(date_format(ar_etime,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s'),' '),
ifnull(ar_eltime,' '),
ar_status
from etl.etl_status es 
where date > ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM `etl_status `
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```